# running karma-cli fails on bamboo agent

Tags: karma-runner, bamboo

I am trying to run karma cli via Bamboo tasks bash Command.

```
node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run
...
node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma: line 3: `var path = require('path');'
```

I also tried it without karma-cli, which brings also an error:

```
node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run
...
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'../lib/cli''
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma: line 3: `require('../lib/cli').run();'
```

package.json (unit test part only):

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.1.3",
"jasmine-jquery": "^2.0.6",
"karma": "^0.12.28",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
"karma-coverage": "^0.2.7",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.2",
"karma-jasmine-jquery": "^0.1.1",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
"karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
"karma-script-launcher": "^0.1.0",
"minimist": "^1.1.0",
"path": "0.4.9",
"phantomjs": "^1.9.16",
```

Any ideas where the problem could be?
Regards, Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: do not run **Bash** Command in Bamboo agent, but use **node.js** plugin

So, node.js task with

```
command: node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma
arguments: start config/karma.conf.js --single-run
```

Then it works fine.